# Settings aren't saving in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm using the registry Settings.settings thingymabob

I'm doing the following in my XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxUsername" 
              Text="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, 
              Path=Username, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
```

This is loading the settings fine.  Now in my Window's `Closing` event I have the following:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

But it wont save settings?

Answer (score 3):

Try to write Text attribute like this:

```
Text="{Binding Source={x:Static prop:Settings.Default}, Path=Username, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

Comment: This seems to be the thing to do